# Как скопировать объект по указателю С++

Tags: c++

Есть указатель на объект

```
Node * parent;
```

Там лежит указатель на объект типа Node, как можно скопировать эту сущность Node, на которую указывает указатель, и создать указатель на эту скопированную копию?

Иными словами что-то вроде:

```
auto cloneParent = &(*parent);
```

это должно работать?

Нужно скопировать сущность по указатель, и создать новый указатель на новую скопированную сущность. Проблема в том что я не могу просто написать

```
auto cloneParent = new Node(parent);
```

Почему? Потому что parent может быть каким-то наследником Node, например Element, и у него может быть переопределен конструктор копирования. По этому нельзя его вызывать явно, надо чтобы он (конструктор копирования) сам вызвался, тот который нужно.

Comment: Да, я мог бы написать что-то вроде
shadowRoot = new Node(*node.shadowRoot);
но что если у меня shadowRoot не Node в какой-то наследник Node? например Element, у которого СВОЙ, переопределенный конструктор копирования. По этому нужно как-то вызвать конструктор копирования неявно. Как?

Comment: Либо я не понял вашего вопроса, либо просто так: `Node* cloneParent = parent;`

Comment: StateItPrimitive, Но что если у меня shadowRoot не Node в какой-то наследник Node? например Element, у которого СВОЙ, переопределенный конструктор копирования. По этому нужно как-то вызвать конструктор копирования неявно. Как?

Comment: StateItPrimitive, и кстати, твой способ просто копирует ссылку, а нужно чтобы скопировалась сущность по ссылке и создалась ссылка на новую скопированную сущность.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых, `Node * parent;` - это не ссылка, а просто указатель. Проверить, что он указывает на пустоту можно только если эту "пустоту" туда вначале записать (то есть, вначале присвоить `nullptr` или что-то другое, что может быть трактовано как "пустота").

Если уже решили ссылку, то она делается немного по-другому.

В том случае, если пустота это `nullptr`, то Ваш код работать не будет - так как разыменования null - это *UB*. Поэтому как минимум нужна проверка. Я бы просто создал функцию, которая все бы это делала сама. Где-то так (набросок, не компилировал!)

```
Node * ownCopy(Node* node) {   
    if (node == nullptr) {
        return nullptr;   
    }
    return node->clone(); // вызовем функцию у нужного наследника, которая правильно его скопирует.
}

// где-то в коде
cloneParent = ownCopy(parent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Для копирования объекта (как вы написали, «сущности») по указателю базового типа требуется содействие со стороны этого объекта. Для этого в базовом классе (ну или классе, тип которого имеет указатель) должен быть объявлен виртуальный метод, который и выполняет все необходимые операции по копированию:

```
class Node
{
public:
    // ...

    /**
     * Возвращает указатель на скопированный объект.
     * Должен быть переопределён в каждом из потомков и иметь вид:
     *
     *     Node* clone() const {return new Type(this);}
     */
    virtual Node* clone() const;
}
```

Если же вы используете C++11 или выше, то стоит возвращать владеющий указатель, чтобы пользователь класса (напару с компилятором) знал о необходимости собственноручного удаления клонированной сущности:

```
/**
 * Возвращает указатель на скопированный объект.
 * Должен быть переопределён в каждом из потомков и иметь вид:
 *
 *     std::unique_ptr<Node> clone() const override {return {new Type(this)};}
 */
virtual std::unique_ptr<Node> clone() const;
```

И да, мы не можем объявить виртуальный оператор копирования, потому что его использование требует разыменования указателя и *object slicing*-а (т. е. отбрасывания всего, что не входит в базовый класс, что приводит к потере фактического типа объекта).

Comment: Разыменование даёт ссылку, никакой срезки ещё нет, пока мы не пробуем присвоить объекту базового класса. Невозможность использовать виртуальный `operator=` возникает в частности из-за различных параметров, требуемых для него в разных классах иерархии.